# how to add rounded image in the center of the container

Tags: image, flutter, containers, rounding, profile

I am creating a profile page, i want top like this

[image]

here is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: new MyAppBar(title: Text("My Profile")
    
     ),
      drawer:drawer(),
      body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
      child:Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
         
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 150,
          color: Colors.blue[500],
          child:  Align(
            alignment:Alignment(-1.4,4.0),
          child:Container(
            
          //margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: 400,
          height: 125,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage('https://patientcaremedical.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/male-catheters.jpg'),
              
            ),
          ),
        ))),
        

      ])));
  }
}
```

and here is its output

[image]

it is round from the bottom, can u please help where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the bottom of your circle looks flat? That has nothing to do with your code. It's because the image you're using has white at the bottom. [Take a look](https://patientcaremedical.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/male-catheters.jpg) for yourself. If you change the `backgroundColor:` of your `Scaffold` to `Colors.red` or something other than white, you will see what I am talking about. All you need to do is use a different image that doesn't have white at the bottom, or crop your current one.